# Simple explanation of passing a structure to a thread

Tags: c, error-handling, pthreads

Not sure why but... what would cause the error

**main.c:126:4: error: cannot convert to a pointer type main.c:126:4: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible    pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(struct arrayslice)’**

I have prototyped this function properly to the best of my knowledge.

```
struct People{

    int count;
    int levels;
};



struct arrayslice *args = &current;
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, countall, (void*) &args);
```

Comment: Something here isn't right and you are not giving us enough info.

What does the prototype for "pthread_create" look like? You are passing wrong arguments to it.

I suspect that you are passing a double pointer, when you should be passing one.

Comment: The third argument is `countall` but you haven't included its declaration, so how can you expect anyone to answer your question?

Comment: C'mon, @RandomGuy, you can find the prototype of pthread_create on the man page, and besides the error message gives the expected type.

Comment: I was a bit lazy, but i suspect this is what it should be
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, countall, (void*) args);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing struct to pthread as an argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196121/passing-struct-to-pthread-as-an-argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the below article. This one really contains the useful information on pthread with relevant example and explanation.

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

> expected ‘void * (*)(void )’ but argument is of type ‘void ()(struct
>   arrayslice)’

Well regarding your compilation error, it is because you are not passing the correct function pointer in the third argument. It looks like your function is

```
void countall(struct arrayslice);
```

However pthread expects that your function should be

```
void* countall(void* arrayslice);
```

Comment: Thanks...new to this and I searched a bunch of other posts on Stack, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417832/cant-create-thread-properly?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196121/passing-struct-to-pthread-as-an-argument and had a hard time figuring it out. I get it now.